# How do i add text to specific cells already containing text given certain criteria?

Tags: excel, vba, text, cell, addition

Worksheet picture

I want to add the text LAURA to column E in front of the existing text in the column when it gets copied to the targeted worksheet:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim wsSource, wsTarget As Worksheet
Dim i, iLastSource, iRowTarget, count As Long
Dim cell As Range

Set wsSource = Worksheets("Stig Jan")
iLastSource = wsSource.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set wsTarget = Worksheets("Laura Jan")

count = 0
With wsSource
iRowTarget = wsTarget.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
For i = 36 To iLastSource
  Set cell = .Cells(i, 4)
  If cell.Font.Bold = False Then
    If cell.Value = "Fælles" Or cell.Value = "Lagt Ud" Then
      wsTarget.Range("A" & iRowTarget & ":H" & iRowTarget).Value = .Range("A" & i & ":H" & i).Value
      wsTarget.Range("D" & iRowTarget).ClearContents
      **wsTarget.Range("E" & iRowTarget).Value = "LAURA. " & cell.Value**
      iRowTarget = iRowTarget + 1
      count = count + 1
    End If
  End If
    If cell.Value = "Fælles" Or cell.Value = "Lagt Ud" Then
    wsSource.Rows(i).Columns("D").Font.Bold = True
    End If
    Next
```

As of now it copies the value in column D instead. So LAURA + Column D

Comment: If you want E instead, offset by 1 column: `"LAURA. " & cell.Offset(, 1).Value`

Comment: Seems like this works like charm. Is this because D was active and you just offset it 1 to E and post value? i am very new to this :) Thank you!

Comment: Your `cell` variable refers to a cell in column 4 (i.e. D) of each row you are processing, so reading the value of the cell offset one column to the right gives you the value from column E.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have gotten alot of help in here. Makes perfect sense now!

Comment: If instead i would put the text in the source sheet before the copy, how would i do that? D:

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: Your example worked perfectly fine copying the text to the target sheet as i initially wanted. But forgot i needed it to be added to the original sheet before it gets copied for some conditional formatting.

Comment: Sounds like you want `cell.offset(, 1).value = "LAURA " & cell.offset(, 1).value`

Comment: Sorry, but like:    `wsTarget.Range("E" & iRowTarget).Value = cell.Offset(, 1).Value = "LAURA " & cell.Offset(, 1).Value` ?

Comment: I am probably doing something wrong, because it doesn't put the text in the existing sheet and just puts False in the target sheet :(

Comment: No, I meant **exactly** the code I posted to update the source sheet.

Comment: ah, i misunderstood. Sorry. Works perfectly now! Thank you for your time Rory. Much appreciated!